# How can I change the json format in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

could someone help me or give me an example of how I can solve this?

I have a type string field that is saved in this format and gives me these values

```
=> "[\"button_p\",\"microphone_e\",\"gate\",\"cabin\",\"temp\"]"
```

I want to call these values ​​a view, and it is displayed like this in my view.

```
accessory type :["button_p","microphone_e","gate","cabin","temp"]
```

How can I make it not look like this?

I would like it to look like this

```
aceessory type: button_p , microphone_e , gate , cabin , temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You already noticed that the string is JSON. I suggest parsing the JSON string and then simple joining the array with `' , '` like this:

```
<%= JSON.parse(attribute_name).join(' , ') %>
```